# Add a mouse click event to generated Textbox fields

Tags: c#

Any idea how to add a mouse click event to generated Textbox fields. Here is the code for generating TextBox fields:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
      TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
      textbox.Location = new Point(60, 25 * count);
      textbox.Size = new Size(301, 20);
      textbox.Name = "textbox_" + (count + 1);
      textbox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBox_Changed);
      panel1.Controls.Add(textbox);
      count++;
      if (count == 4)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("");
          button1.Enabled = false;
      }
}
```

The code below must be in the method that handles the mouse click event for every generated Textbox field:

```
TextBox txtName = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textbox_1", true)[0];
TextBox txth = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textbox_2", true)[0];

if (txtName != null)
{

}
```

Comment: not clear what you are looking for ?

Comment: how to create mouse click event in generated textbox fields

Comment: because its generated I cant create Mouse click event.

Comment: why not? did you test it?

Comment: You're literally already doing it with a `TextChanged` event... the mouse click one is pretty much identical.

Comment: Maybe you can provide more information of what you are trying to accomplish with the MouseClick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
int count = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
    textbox.Location = new Point(60, 25 * count);
    textbox.Size = new Size(301, 20);
    textbox.Name = "textbox_" + (count + 1);
    textbox.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.TextBox_MouseClick);
    textbox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.TextBox_Changed);
    panel1.Controls.Add(textbox);
    count++;
    if (count == 4)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("");
        button1.Enabled = false;
    }
}
private void TextBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{ 
    TextBox txtName = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textbox_1", true)[0]; 
    TextBox txth = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textbox_2", true)[0]; 

    if (txtName != null) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
}
```

When I preform a click on a TextBox this MessageBox window appears:

[image: When I preform a click on a TextBox this MessageBox window appears:]

I would also change the `TextBox_MouseClick` method to :

```
private void TextBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control[] txtName = this.Controls.Find("textbox_1", true);
    Control[] txth = this.Controls.Find("textbox_2", true);

    if ((TextBox)txtName[0] != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
}
```

Because if you create only one TextBox and perform a click on it you will get a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` because the second TextBox isn't created so the array that holds you second TextBox is empty.

Comment: ahmm not working on 
`private void TextBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtName = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textbox_1", true)[0];
    TextBox txth = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textbox_2", true)[0];

    if (txtName != null)
    {

    }
}`

Comment: I run the code an had no problems. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: did not respond with a click . `if (txtName != null)
    {
Messagebox.show("Test");
    }`

Comment: no did not get any error.  for testing i just added messagebox

Comment: Copy my code above and it has to work maybe you forgot to add `textbox.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.TextBox_MouseClick);`

Comment: I assume that in the mouse click function OP is trying to get the actual clicked text box... which would simply be `TextBox clicked = (TextBox)sender;`

Comment: @Nyerguds but why is he then testing if the first textbox ("textbox_1") isn't null. When you click it this means that textbox1 is the sender so why testing if it isn't null

Comment: Beats me. But looking for hardcoded strings for dynamically added text boxes seems really bizarre to me. If he just wants to know how many there are, he could keep a counter, or store the created objects in a `List<TextBox>` and check its size.

Comment: I agree with you @Nyerguds. I think the OP has to provide more information about what he really wants to accomplish in the MouseClick event

Comment: @SlavenHvar Thanks, Codes Works. 
`Control[]' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'Control[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: You have to add `using System.Windows.Forms;` or in the `TextBox_MouseClick` method add `System.Windows.Forms.Control[]`.

Comment: maybe ill create a new question for this.

Comment: I run the code and had no problems. Have you added `using System.Windows.Forms;` to your code because your error states that you are mising a using directive. If the first part doesn't work try to change `Control[] txtName` to `var txtName` and `Control[] txth` to `var txth` and it should work.

Comment: Or you could change `Control[] txtName` to `System.Windows.Forms.Control[] txtName` and `Control[] txth` to `System.Windows.Forms.Control[] txth`